# How to make a copy of my magento site to my computer

Tags: magento-1.9, git, transfer

I am making a copy of our Magento website using FTP file transfer. My goal is to set a copy of the website and start making changes offline and start using git to keep the site backed up and updated.

I am looking for direction on how to complete this task correctly and successfully.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Download your magento source from server.
- Export your `mysql` database from server you can check `local.xml` for database configuration.
- then put your source code in wamp/xampp/lamp project directory.
- import mysql database in phpmyadmin.
- change `web/unsecure/base_url` from `core_config_data` table.
- `clear cache` & `re-index` data
- Initialize `init git` in your magento directory push the source from their.

Comment: The download is done. So I will continue with the following steps. I will let you know how everything went. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to download your site from the live version to a local version, using FTP you can simply follow the subsequent steps:

1. Log in to your hosting provider (e.g GoDaddy, BlueHost, etc)
2. Set-up / Make a note of your FTP account details (You'll need an account that has full permissions)
3. Download an FTP Client such as WinSCP or Filezilla.
4. Enter the FTP Host, FTP User, and FTP Password, and Port Number 21 for FTP and 22 for SFTP.
5. Connect to your server via FTP, and then simply highlight all files and download them all, or select an option that simply allows you to download all files.

Now that your FTP set-up is complete, you will now be able to upload changes to a folder on your server, and then transfer them from this folder to your public folder. You can upload straight from local to the public side of your webpage, but this isn't recommended at all.

Hopefully that answers your question directly, however, you might want to look into SSH access also if you're working with Magento.

***Edit :** Someone made a good point, be sure to make a local copy of your database also, so that your system can run locally using a backup. It's also good practice to have some kind of backup you can use in the event of total failure, so maybe do this often.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking to set up a git repository to commit updates etc and then deploy the updates . So far it has taken several hours and still downloading.

Comment: @Eduarto That's expected if it's a full download of the entire system, but don't worry - this is the purpose of git, so once this part's done it's only the small changes from there.

Comment: It finally finished.

Comment: @Eduarto Good to hear. If you're happy with the answer, please accept it for the benefit of others who find the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to upload source faster, you can zip the folder and download.
if you have cpanel or ssh accout, you can do