# Redirection issue after website duplication with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, multistore, migration, redirection

I'm currently working a Magento 2 (*2.1.14 exactly*) mutli-store website and I have some problems for create a **development website**. I'm the only back-end developer in the company and had never work on Magento 2 before so I'm learning little by little how does it works.

We need to upgrade the Magento version, some plugins and add some functionnalities but I really need to have a clean **development setup** to work in, without the fear to break the production website.

---

#### Problem ⚠️

**Current mode : *developer***

I followed these steps below but the dev website (*dev.mywebsite.ch*) still redirect me on the production server (*www.mywebsite.ch*).

1. Create folder on server `dev.website.ch`
2. Create a sub-domain and point to the newly created folder
3. Copy all files and folders in it with `rsync -avz source/* dest/`
4. Create a database dump file`dump.sql`
5. Clean the dump file (advice from [MgtCommerce](https://www.mgt-commerce.com/)) like `sed "s/\/\*[^\/]*DEFINER.*\*\///" dump.sql > clean_dump.sql`
6. Import the dump file in the suitable DB
7. Change the database detail in `app/etc/env.php`
8. Change base URL and base secure URL in `core_config_data` table in the dev database

I also executed all commands I use when I want to upload a new thing/bug fix (**SSH**) :

- `chmod 775 /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/*/ -R`
- `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US fr_FR de_DE`
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`
- `php bin/magento cache:clean`

---

**Questions I used...**

- [How to make a copy of my magento site to my computer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258064/how-to-make-a-copy-of-my-magento-site-to-my-computer)
- [How duplicate your live store on a development store and try installation on it in advance](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188409/how-duplicate-your-live-store-on-a-development-store-and-try-installation-on-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cache

Try running the below commands

```
rm -rf var/cache var/view_preprocessed var/page_cache generated/* pub/static/frontend
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This should solve your problem

---

## SSL

If SSL isn't enabled on your development domain, make sure to use `http://` in all `core_config_data` table entries (and not `https://`)

Comment: I tried this and the Anas solution above but it still redirect me to one of the store view (multi-store). I also tried to find the `design/head/includes` path in the `core_config_data` table described in [this article](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-move-magento-2-root-url-to-another-domain.html) but the value doesn't look the same : `<meta name="p:domain_verify" content="ce45202ccd87ab3dabad07b683d27e79"/>`

Comment: Can you please check  your  network tab to check how the redirect works? Also please search for the redirecting domain name in core_config_data

Comment: Here is the result @rajmohanr (301 error) : [listing](https://imgur.com/RpNSa3F) & [detail](https://imgur.com/PDD2tdF)

Comment: Can you please clear your browser cache and try now. I think so the page is working fine for me without redirection

Comment: I am getting redirected from http://dev.riseup.ch to http://dev.riseup.ch/english/

Comment: The front-end looks fine for me too but I can't access the admin page (I'm redirected) : http://dev.riseup.ch/admin

Comment: Have you searched for www.riseup.ch in core_config_data since if you have set admin URL in configuration

Comment: Have you checked it?

Comment: Yes! I found the solution : I was right but we haven't a SSL for the development domain so I changed `https://dev.riseup.ch/` for `http://dev.riseup.ch/` in the `core_config_data` table

Answer (score 0):

the redirect problem was due to magento cache.

try to deleted everything from var/ folder for your magento site(dev.website.ch). after that you cleared your browser's cache/cookies or try with private browser for good measure & it worked!